# AES homomorphic updates

Tags: aes, homomorphic-encryption

I am looking for some help regarding something I am trying to do and I think to solution might be in Homomorphic encryption.

Person **A** and **B** encrypt the same number(unsinged long) **N** using AES with different keys.

Person C runs a transformation function **TF** based on some random secret input **S** on both cyphertexts. A and B decrypt their own transformed cypher texts and gain the same **Nt** result.

The idea is that the secret used in the transformation function must not leak information as it might be used hundreds of millions of times (practically in public).

What I am looking for is a simple transformation function on this long/bigint that is deterministic.
Homomorphic encryption, as far I read, could theoretically do this on AES encrypted cyphertexts.

The transformation function doesn't need to be complex as long as it doesn't leak information. Some simple multiplications followed by a mod (could be int256) should do the trick. However, I am not sure if this falls in the partial/somewhat homomorphic encryption category and how I should go about.

I am a developer and not a well-educated mathematician, so ideally I am looking for some code examples on github if it is possible at all. I did find some libs but they mainly seem to focus on either FHE or public key encryption. While I want to use AES/Symmetric and not sure if I even need the 'full' version.

Thnx in advance!

Comment: It might be better if you explained the actual problem you're trying to solve, and not outline a suggested solution...

Comment: Ok, so on a more abstract level you want to realize the following computation: $A$ and $B$ both have the secret number $N$ and $C$ has the secret input $S$ and you want $A$ and $B$ to learn $F(N,S)$ without having $C$ learn $N$ nor having $A$ / $B$ learn $S$. What are your requirements for $F$ in this case? Because clearly $F(N,S)=N$ (that is C sending back the ciphertexts verbatim) would satisfy the above scenario. Do you also require $F$ to be unpredictable to $A$ and $B$? As for a solution, it sounds like you're looking for _oblivious pseudo-random functions_.

Comment: I will take a look at OPRF's, maybe I described it wrongly. The function runs on each person's, A and B's, cyphertexts (one each). When the result of the function is decrypted **another** number **Nt** is returned which is the same for person A and B. Without person C learning either N or Nt and person A & B not learning about S.

Comment: From your revised problem description, an OPRF is exactly what you're looking for

Comment: I am not sure if OPRF is going to work. But I get why it is proposed given my problem description.

Person B actually never gets to see **N** but only **Nt**/ This because the encryption is done 1 time by Person A then published(public info) and transformed. Now Person A encrypts it again with a second key and encrypts it with persons C public key. This package + the key is given to person B. Who can give the package to person C who does it's secret transformation and then returns the result to Person B. With Key 2, he can see the result.

Comment: So the ideal functionality would be that of an OPRF but instead of the non-key inputter only a specified third party would learn the result? That is A inputs $N$, B inputs nothing, $C$ inputs a secret key and in the end A and C learn nothing and $B$ learns $F(S,N)$ but neither $S$ nor $N$? (Optionally augmented with B inputting a key of its own and receiving an encryption of $F(S,N)$ under said key)

Comment: A does learn the result of F(S,N). But because A encrypts the new(New key for AES encryption) cypher text with a public key of C, B will not learn the input N but only the result of F(S,N).

Hence I thought that having a homomorphic transformation function that can work on the AES ciphertext, it could work.

Comment: Are you _insisting_ on AES being somehow magically being used here (and thus forcing some form of homomorphic encryption)? Or would you be content with a protocol that allows your three parties to work together so that A inputs N, B inputs nothing, C inputs its secret and in the end A and B learn F(S,N) but not S and C doesn't learn N? (also please use @SEJPM in your comment replies or else I may forget to manually check this question and never reply...)

Comment: So essentially what I'm asking is: Please [edit] your question to describe who should input what information, should learn what information with what security properties, or even better describe the context under which the current question text was created. Because chances are there is a way to create a Secure Multi-Party Computation Protocol that will do this without involving some exotic homomorphic encryption.

Comment: @SEJPM Thank you for helping! I found my answer outside of the AES realm. Two actually one: the Paillier crypto system worked but also the BFV/BGF homomorphic scheme's.